# How to push/shovel/append active record relation correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a fairly complex search form that allows for multiple duplicate nested fields to be submitted at once.  I generate unique id's on clone so i can separate them using jquery.  I then iterate over the duplicates and do something like the following:

So i have something like:

{..., "search"=>{"searches"=>{}, "searches_0"=>{}...{other_attributes}}

```
def search_post
    search = []
    params.each do |k, v|
       search << do_search(params, v)
    end
end
```

---

```
def do_search(search, v)
    search_array = []
    search = Model.where() if v[:this_param].present?
    search = Model.where() if v[:that_param].present?
    # it will be only one of the `search` as this_param or that_param can't be searched 
    together

    search_array << search.where(attr: search[:attr]) if attr.present?
    search_array << search.where(attr_2: search[:attr_2]) if attr_2.present?
    search_array << search.where(attr_3 search[:attr_3]) if attr_3.present?

    search_array.uniq
end
```

This gives a result like:

```
[#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<LineItem id: 15, created_at: "2020-01-03 15:49:19", updated_at: "2020-01-03 15:49:19", ...>]>, #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<LineItem id: 14, created_at: "2020-01-03 15:49:19", updated_at: "2020-01-03 15:49:19", ...>]>]
```

I obviously get an array but I need to do more queries on it.

I have tried using `search.reduce([], :concat).uniq` but this only removes all of the results and only keeps the ActiveRecord::Relation aspect of the array.

What I need is to shovel the results from the loop and be able to use `where` on it.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Can't you start with `Model.all` and then filter out the results with multiple `#where`'s ?

Comment: Well, I could do if statements but there are more params involved so this way is much cleaner so i wanted to see if i can get a solution more lke this.  For instance,  I have 3 more params that are selected through checkbox so instead of checking if those params exist, I can just shovel them in.  I am about to update the search method so its there

Comment: Otherwise, I would need to do something like `if attr && attr_2 && attr_3 elsif attr && attr_2 elsif attr && attr_3` and get each combination.  Or do you see another way

Comment: Can you start with `Model.all` and use reduce across the array of params to build the resulting Relation set?  Something along the lines of `params.reduce(Model.all) { |results, param| results.where(param) }`.

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You're passing `params` to `#do_search` and then you overwrite the `search` argument in the `#do_search` method on the second line if `this` (what is `this` ?) or you call `#where` on params. I suggest you post valid code and a minimal reproducible example, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: @jebentier yes but without the conditionals it wouldn't work because if I do `where(attr)` and then after do where(attr_2)` the first one narrows it too far so the attr_+ ones aren't searching the entirety of the records from the first initial where

Comment: @Viktor i updated it so you can see how it works.  See the comment

Comment: This looks like a job for a query object.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you can try using a query object:

```
class ModelQuery
  def initialize(initial_scope = Model.all)
    @initial_scope = initial_scope
  end

  def call(params)
    scoped = by_this_param(initial_scope, params[:this_param])
    scoped = by_that_param(initial_scope, params[:that_param])
    scoped = by_other_param(initial_scope, params[:other])
    # ...
    scoped
  end

  def by_this_param(s, this_param = nil)
    this_param ? s.where(this_attr: this_param) : s
  end

  def by_that_param(s, that_param = nil)
    that_param ? s.where(that_attr: that_param) : s
  end

  # ...

  def by_other(s, other = nil)
    other ? s.where(other_attr: other) : s
  end
end
```

You can then do things like:

```
q = ModelQuery.new
# or perhaps...
# q = ModelQuery.new(Model.where(whatever: "however"))
q.call params
q.order(whatever_column: :asc).group(:however)
```

Obviously you need to adapt and extend the code above to your variable names/parameters. Another upside of using the query object pattern is that it gives you a subtle nudge to structure your parameters coherently so you can pass from view and return from AR quickly, without much fiddling about with the input/output.

Give it a try!